# Is troubleshooting AppArmor with 'teardown' unsafe?

Tags: security, apparmor

I understand there is a safer, more targeted way to troubleshoot AppArmor's possible contribution to an issue than completely stopping the service and tearing down AppArmor profiles.  Can someone give me the details, and the advantages of the better approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I was thinking of (from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingApparmor ) -- "complain mode" .  This doesn't address the issue of relative merits or consequences of this versus other debugging methods.

> When debugging, it may also be useful
>   to put apparmor into 'complain' mode.
>   This will allow your application to
>   function normally while apparmor
>   reports accesses that are not in the
>   profile. To enable 'complain' mode,
>   use:
>
> ```
> sudo aa-complain /path/to/bin
> ```
>
> where '/path/to/bin' is the absolute
>   path to the binary, as reported in the
>   'profile=...' portion of the 'audit'
>   entry. Eg:
>
> ```
> sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/slapd
> ```
>
> To re-enable enforcing mode, use
>   'aa-enforce' instead:
>
> ```
> sudo aa-enforce /path/to/bin
> ```
>
> To disable a profile:
>
> ```
> sudo touch /etc/apparmor.d/disable/path.to.bin
> sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/path.to.bin
> ```

When troubleshooting then, if there is something broken that appears to be related to a spooky permissions problem ('Hmm, looks like access control, but it's not a Unix permissions problem, or an NFS issue, or PAM issue, or a media mounting goof, etc. -- perhaps it's AppArmor.'), Kees Cook points out  that best course of action is too check your system logs.  Notably, per Kees Cook, "the output of `dmesg` will report all AppArmor denials, and will include the profile."

Comment: The output of `dmesg` will report all AppArmor denials, and will include the profile. It is not needed to ever guess at whether AppArmor is responsible or not. Either there was a denial in the logs and you can disable that profile, or there wasn't. :)

Comment: @Kees -- Brilliant, thanks.  So I only have to guess if I don't know what I'm doing.  Ha.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Kees -- I guess there is still a chance (in some possible universe) that the kernel, LSM subsystem, or AppArmor itself could have out-of-spec behavior (i.e., a bug).  Which might be tested with service tear... no, no, even in that vanishingly small spot of possible reality where this might occur, it would probably be better just to open a bug report.

Comment: Note that in natty, you can disable a specific profile with the aa-disable(1) command.